# Workbox precache : Based on user type

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox, sw-precache

I don't want to preCache for all users but only for members. I want to do this to avoid unnecessary load on the server and unnecessarily caching for one-time visitors.

So when the visitor logs in, I send a message to the service worker.  In the below snippet on the service worker, the 'Message Received' is logged in console. But the images are not cached. And there is no error message.

If I directly place `precacheAndRoute(images)` below the `const images = [....];` then the images are cached properly.

I am new to service workers. And any help is highly appreciated.

```js
const images = [....];
addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data.type === 'cacheImages') {
    console.log('Message Received');
    precacheAndRoute(images);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way [precaching works in Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching) is by caching the files when the service worker is `installed`.

You are calling `precacheAndRoute` inside an event in the SW, the SW is already installed, it won't execute the precacheAndRoute then.

You might want to checkout the [image cache recipe](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-recipes#image_cache) too.